# Trained maskrcnn follwoing sagemaker example notebook, got warning: Your model will NOT be servable with SageMaker TensorFlow Serving container

Tags: tensorflow, deployment, model, containers, amazon-sagemaker

I'm training a maskrcnn model following an AWS example [notebook](https://test-j-zc5q.notebook.us-east-2.sagemaker.aws/examples/preview?example_id=%2Fhome%2Fec2-user%2Fsample-notebooks%2Fadvanced_functionality%2Fdistributed_tensorflow_mask_rcnn%2Fmask-rcnn-s3.ipynb)

The only thing that I didn't follow is I didn't use subnets and security_group_ids.
I trained on the whole COCO2017 set, after 19 hours, the training status showed the training was completed.

But in CloudWatch, the log shows "Your model will NOT be servable with SageMaker TensorFlow Serving container. The model artifact was not saved in the TensorFlow SavedModel directory structure"

I'm very confused. Is it expected as the trained model of this maskrcnn? If so, it seems this model can not be deployed. Because according to this [doc](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/tensorflow/deploying_tensorflow_serving.html), the deploy action is to happen within SageMaker TensorFlow Serving containers. And the truth is, I tried deploying it, and it failed.

If anyone has successfully trained/deployed a MaskRcnn model on SageMaker, or know anything about this issue, I'd appreciate it very much if you could share your insights! Great thanks!

Following is the last few lines of the training log from CloudWatch:

```
0 S root      3225    33  0  80   0 -  1157 -      20:19 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c ps -elf | grep "python3 /mask-rcnn-tensorflow/MaskRCNN/train.py"

0 S root      3227  3225  0  80   0 -  3303 -      20:19 ?        00:00:00 grep python3 /mask-rcnn-tensorflow/MaskRCNN/train.py

training processes running: 0

Worker algo-2 training completed.

2021-10-06 20:19:51,168 sagemaker_tensorflow_container.training WARNING  Your model will NOT be servable with SageMaker TensorFlow Serving container. The model artifact was not saved in the TensorFlow SavedModel directory structure:

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#structure_of_a_savedmodel_directory

2021-10-06 20:19:51,169 sagemaker-containers INFO     Reporting training SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution.

In the case I described above, I used AWS Samples Mask R-CNN image for training.

Recently, I trained the model using TensorPack Faster-RCNN/Mask-RCNN image, and the model was trained successfully. Also, in the process of making an inference of this model, if I choose TensorPack image as well, I can successfully deploy this model!